# Question about the .html() function of jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Right now when I replace content inside the "foo" div, the new content appears right away. Is 
there a way to have the new content fade in slowly.

```
<div class="foo">Initial content to be replaced</div>

$('div.foo').html('New content');
```

I know about the fadeIn() function, the reason why I ask this question is because I can't understand how it can be technically possible since the foo div was never hidden to begin with, so how will it be able to "fade in". But still in case someone can think of a way it would be most super.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this: `$('div.foo').html('New Content').hide().fadeIn();`

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers here don't account for the fact that the transitions take time -- the html will get replaced in the middle the fadeOut and look like a mistake.

Assuming you want a fadeOut to complete, then replace html, then fadeIn, use a callback:

```
$('div.foo').fadeOut(function () {
   $(this).html('New content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: OP didn't want it to fadeout.. just fade in.

Answer (score 1):

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wdYfT/1/)***

```
$('div.foo').html('New content').hide().fadeIn();
```

You hide it first, then fade it in

Comment: your example doesn't do a whole lot, since it performs it's magic on load. Maybe on click or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("div.foo").hide("slow").html("New Content").show("slow");
```

This will fade the div out, change the content, and then fade it in, which might achieve the effect you're looking for.